# How do I replace a specific URL in a "href" attribute using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, href

I'd like to replace only the `href` URL that has a single leading forward slash (`/`) using a regular expression.

Here is my string:

```
var p = '<link href="/example.com"/> <link href="//example2.com"/>';
```

Here is my code, but it's matching the `href` attribute of both elements.

```
var p = '<link href="/example.com"/> <link href="//example2.com"/>';
var re = /href="\//gi;
var newstr = p.replace(re, 'href="/baseurl/');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this instead:

```js
const links = `
  <a href="/example.com">Example</a>
  <a href='//example.com'>Example</a>
`;

const re = /href=(["']{1})\/{1}([^\/])/gi;

console.log(links.replace(re, 'href=$1/baseurl/$2'));
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but your regex also replaces strings like  '<a href='//example.com'>Example</a>'. I would like it to skip all href url that start with //

Comment: @Emz The following part of the regex: `\/{1}` specifically limits the amount of forward slashes (`/`) to one.

Comment: Just add another string like this  '<a href='//example.com'>Example</a>'  to constant links and run the code. You see that is will be replaced as well to this '<a href='/baseurl//example.com'>Example</a>/

Comment: @Emz I've found the problem and have updated my answer. The solution works in the snippet, try it out and let me know if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var p = '<link href="/example.com"/> <link href="//example2.com"/>';
var re = /href="\/([A-z0-9])/gi;
var newstr = p.replace(re, 'href="/baseurl/$1');
console.log(newstr);
```

This will replace only single slash urls and also if there are multiple of such urls also will be replaced

Comment: It's replacing the first letter as well. i.e it's removing the letter E from the word example. <link href="/baseurl/xample.com"/> <link href="//example2.com"/>

Comment: @Emz I had fixed that issue now.